# MySQL query to get table name with numerically highest number

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-order-by

I have a WordPress multisite database, which has a lot of orphan tables I need to get rid of. The names are structured like this. The number in the table name is the site ID.

```
wp_9892_wc_booking_relationships
wp_10001_wc_booking_relationships
wp_18992_wc_deposits_payment_plans
wp_20003_followup_coupons
wp_245633_followup_coupon_logs
```

I want to make a query to find out the highest site ID from the table names.

I've tried queries like this

```sql
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'base table'
AND table_name REGEXP '^wp_[0-9]+_[a-z0-9]+'
ORDER BY table_name DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

But that sorts the results in an unexpected way: I get

```
wp_9_woocommerce_log
```

When with `LIMIT 10` I see there are names with higher numbers:

```
wp_99_woocommerce_log
wp_999_woocommerce_log
wp_999_wc_webhooks
wp_999_wc_download_log
wp_999_wcpv_per_product_shipping_rules
wp_999_wcpv_commissions
wp_9999_wcpv_per_product_shipping_rules
wp_9999_wcpv_commissions
wp_9998_wc_points_rewards_user_points_log
```

Is this something that's doable with a SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following data example.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
table_name  varchar(255) );

insert into test values
('wp_99_woocommerce_log'),
('wp_999_woocommerce_log'),
('wp_999_wc_webhooks'),
('wp_999_wc_download_log'),
('wp_999_wcpv_per_product_shipping_rules'),
('wp_999_wcpv_commissions'),
('wp_9999_wcpv_per_product_shipping_rules'),
('wp_9999_wcpv_commissions'),
('wp_9998_wc_points_rewards_user_points_log');
```

Using,

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM test
order by (substring_index(substring_index(table_name, 'wp_', -1), '_', 1) * 1 )  desc ;
```

Will give the following result:

```
table_name
wp_9999_wcpv_per_product_shipping_rules
wp_9999_wcpv_commissions
wp_9998_wc_points_rewards_user_points_log
wp_999_woocommerce_log
wp_999_wc_webhooks
wp_999_wc_download_log
wp_999_wcpv_per_product_shipping_rules
wp_999_wcpv_commissions
wp_99_woocommerce_log
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/590L44Xr

Using substring_index twice we get the number between `wp_` and the second `_`.

`* 1` is a shortcut to cast the varchar to int.

In your case it will be something like

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'base table'
AND table_name REGEXP '^wp_[0-9]+_[a-z0-9]+'
ORDER BY  (substring_index(substring_index(table_name, 'wp_', -1), '_', 1) * 1 )   DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this gets the expected result! @nbk's method also works – I'm not knowledgeable enough to say which is better, but opted for this one as a tiny bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to extryct the numbers and sort it

Example

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (`tb` varchar(34))
;
    
INSERT INTO table1
    (`tb`)
VALUES
    ('wp_9892_wc_booking_relationships'),
    ('wp_10001_wc_booking_relationships'),
    ('wp_18992_wc_deposits_payment_plans'),
    ('wp_20003_followup_coupons'),
    ('wp_245633_followup_coupon_logs')
;
```

> ```
> Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT tb FROM table1 ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(tb,"[0-9]+") + 0  DESC LIMIT 1
```

| tb |
| --- |
| wp_245633_followup_coupon_logs |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I0WDo0Lr)

So your query will look like

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type = 'base table'
AND table_name REGEXP '^wp_[0-9]+_[a-z0-9]+'
ORDER BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(table_name,"[0-9]+") + 0  DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I've checked it against a result I got through a more manual way, and this works! Accepting @ergest-basha's answer purely because it ran 0.198 seconds faster for me.